# Entity Framework Unique Across Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Given the following table

Year - Int 
EmployeeOne - String 
EmployeeTwo - String

How can we prevent duplicate values across different columns.

Take the following scenario

```
Year | EmployeeOne | EmployeeTwo
2020 | 0001        | 0002
2020 | 0003        | 0004
```

This is fine as EmployeeOne and EmployeeTwo don't contain the same values.

However given this scenario

```
Year | EmployeeOne | EmployeeTwo
2020 | 0001        | 0002
2020 | 0003        | 0001
```

I want this to fail. As EmployeeOne column has 0001 with a year of 2020 and EmployeeTwo column also has 0001 with a year of 2020

I've tried putting in the place the following composite keys

- Year & EmployeeOne
- Year & EmployeeTwo
- Year & EmployeeOne & EmployeeTwo

But having no joy

Comment: 2 unique composite indexes should be enough. (Year, EmployeeOne) + (Year, EmployeeTwo).

Comment: @IvanStoev would that catch the second scenario there? I had                 builder.HasKey(x => new {x.Year, x.EmployeeOne});
builder.HasAlternateKey(x => new {x.Year, x.EmployeeTwo});

however it didn't catch the example in second scenario

Comment: Yup, sorry, you are right - unfortunately it's not sufficient. You would need some sort of an unique index(es) over persisted calculated column(s), which depends on the target database. The equivalent of (Year, Min(EmployeeOne, EmployeeTwo)) + (Year, Max(EmployeeOne, EmployeeTwo)). Or ((Year, Min(EmployeeOne, EmployeeTwo),  Max(EmployeeOne, EmployeeTwo)).

Answer (score 0):

If its not possible with Table Constraints then you can do validation in trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial if your data model has (Year, Employee, Role) instead of (Year, EmployeeOne, EmployeeTwo).  Then a key of (Year,Employee) ensures this constraint.